# Why is no used the Utilitarian "And what?" answer?

Tags: reference-request, utilitarianism

Utilitarismus is very hated for going against things like the right to live, steal and so on.

Utilitarians typically have tried to reconcile the doctrine with this common-sense aspect of ethics.

But most of this complains and most of ethics have been all about creating mental experiments to "show" the unacceptability of the consequences of the rival ethical theory. But Humans are emotional beings, reason is no more than a mean to regulate the emotions and expand comprehensions, and therefore all analysis of a ethical moral experiment will be no more than an emotional reaction either because the individual used reason to conclude that is goes against one of his goals (goals are emotional preferences), or because he feels agression, either case all reaction to such experiments are always emotional. Thus the Gedankenexperiment method of ethics is fundamentally flawed because it cannot prove more than feelings, and every attempt of defend it will be no more than a attempt to defend emotivism (and doubt that more than a minory wants to accept this price).

So why this is no the standard response by Utilitariasnism to all of this accusations?, and they have already used it?

Comment: Just for reference: Is there any non-trivial set of ideas that has received/produced the sort of response you would prefer? Pretty sure that just about any set of ideas you could hold up has had risible things said on its behalf and in attacking it. The world is jammed up with humans. What are you going to do?

Comment: Because the point of utilitarianism is, ultimately, to advance ethical goals, whether their source is emotional or not. If it fails to do that it is of little use. Those goals come not from reason but from "moral intuitions", and the point of experiments is to test utilitarian prescriptions against them in a raw form. The source of intuitions may or may not be emotions, if it is then so much the worse for utilitarianism, if not then "cannot prove more than feelings" is false. Either way, this response fails.

Comment: @Conifold Did no Richard Brandt (Brandt 1979) and Richard Hare (Hare 1973) responded to this objection with the "And what?" response ?

Comment: Brandt, R., 1979, A Theory of the Good and the Right, Oxford: Oxford University Press.
–––, 1990, ‘The Science of Man and Wide Reflective Equilibrium’, Ethics, 100: 259–278.
Hare, R.M., 1973, ‘Rawls' Theory of Justice’, Philosophical Quarterly, 23: 144–55; 241–51.